# React-native detect click on WebView

Tags: webview, onclick, react-native

Is there solution to detect click anywhere on reacts-native WebView? Tried to put it inside TouchableOpacity but I'm getting errors. Is there some work around it, to detect click?

Answer (score 0):

This will be a great feature if react native team can add it in the future. Currently this is still an open issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/586

Somebody provide a suggestion at there you can give it a try. But it is better wait for facebook team to provide a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Any events taking place inside a webview is sandboxed from the rest of the application. This is by design of this native component, not a limitation of React Native.

What you will need to do is to manually bubble up the event that you are interested in from the webview to your app yourself.

You can currently do so by using [react-native-webview-bridge](https://github.com/alinz/react-native-webview-bridge). You set a global listener to the DOM event that you are interested in. Once you catch it, you send it to your application via the bridge.